# How to convert long string to list of objects

Tags: javascript

How can I convert the following into a list of objects with javascript.

data:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f2d3db90fded9f3fa2d1"},"name":"Audi","price":52642},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f2dedb90fded9f3fa2d2"},"name":"Mercedes","price":57127},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f304db90fded9f3fa2d3"},"name":"Skoda","price":9000},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f368db90fded9f3fa2d4"},"name":"Volvo","price":29000},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f370db90fded9f3fa2d5"},"name":"Bentley","price":350000},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f378db90fded9f3fa2d6"},"name":"Citroen","price":21000},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f37fdb90fded9f3fa2d7"},"name":"Hummer","price":41400},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f389db90fded9f3fa2d8"},"name":"Volkswagen","price":21600}
```

When I do typeof on the data I get string. What I am trying to do is create a list with an entry for every object. I tried JSON.parse but it errors on the commas between the curly braces.Thank you.

Comment: _"but it errors on the commas between the curly braces"_ - Because it's invalid JSON. Wherever you get that string from they should fix their code to output correct formatted JSON.

Comment: Please visit, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON and read on what valid JSON is. Your JSON data is incorrect. Also, a JSON validator https://jsonlint.com/. You got lucky with a good response answer, but that is not always possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that particular string – comma-separated JSON objects – you can wrap it in array brackets `[]` and parse it:

```
var data = `{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f2d3db90fded9f3fa2d1"},"name":"Audi","price":52642},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f2dedb90fded9f3fa2d2"},"name":"Mercedes","price":57127},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f304db90fded9f3fa2d3"},"name":"Skoda","price":9000},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f368db90fded9f3fa2d4"},"name":"Volvo","price":29000},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f370db90fded9f3fa2d5"},"name":"Bentley","price":350000},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f378db90fded9f3fa2d6"},"name":"Citroen","price":21000},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f37fdb90fded9f3fa2d7"},"name":"Hummer","price":41400},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d96f389db90fded9f3fa2d8"},"name":"Volkswagen","price":21600}`;
var parsed = JSON.parse(`[${data}]`);
```

Then `parsed` will be an array of 8 entries:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5d96f2d3db90fded9f3fa2d1"
    },
    "name": "Audi",
    "price": 52642
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5d96f2dedb90fded9f3fa2d2"
    },
    "name": "Mercedes",
    "price": 57127
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5d96f304db90fded9f3fa2d3"
    },
    "name": "Skoda",
    "price": 9000
  },
...
```

Comment: _"comma-separated JSON objects"_ - [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @Andreas To be as nitpicky, I mean the grammatical construct described in the JSON spec as `object`. This, you know: https://www.json.org/img/object.png